# Stored procedure fails when called from Service Broker but runs from SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

We are using Service Broker in SQL Server 2008R2 as a simple job scheduler. We send a message to the broker and it sets it to process on the requested date/time.

We have a job (stored procedure) that gets automatically scheduled by user actions in a Sharepoint site, and it's been running just fine for about a year. This stored procedure creates 2 tables if they don't exist, truncates them if they do exist, then calls 2 other stored procedures (in series) to populate each of the tables.

A few weeks ago, the 2nd of the two stored procedures started failing when the main proc "job" was initiated by the SB. If I go into SSMS, I can execute the "job" stored procedure and it runs to completion without issue (i.e. both called stored procedures execute without issue, and both tables are populated).

Our company, in its infinite wisdom, decided to terminate the guy who set up the Service Broker and wrote these stored procedures. I understand the stored procedures, and am beginning to get a bit of a handle on SB, but I'm at a loss as to why the 2nd stored procedure will execute from SSMS, but fails when called from the Service Broker.

The only thing I can think of is that the Service was created with this command:

```
CREATE SERVICE [//ScheduledJobService]
AUTHORIZATION [user ID]
ON QUEUE [dbo].[ScheduledJobQueue] ([//ScheduledJobContract])
```

and that something happened with his ID on the date that it stopped working. However, that doesn't account for why part of the code will execute, and how other tasks in the Service Broker are continuing to execute.

I'm at a loss for where to look and how to track this down, so any trouble shooting tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read http://rusanu.com/2006/01/12/why-does-feature-not-work-under-activation/

Answer (score 0):

Service broker, as a background process, needs to run things as certain users. In my broker installations I have normally created a special user for this (i.e. `Broker_User`) with rights to whatever it needs to execute and nothing else.

If the authorizing account for that service or for the broker queue activation procedure is revoked, things will fail.

To really trace this we need to know:

- The details of the queue (create statement etc)
- The details of the activation procedure referenced above
- Information about the accounts involved

It's also possible there's code inside one of the SPs that uses `EXECUTE AS` which would cause an issue if the account is removed or revoked.

Comment: `CREATE QUEUE [dbo].[ScheduledJobQueue] WITH STATUS = ON , RETENTION = OFF , ACTIVATION (  STATUS = ON , PROCEDURE_NAME = [dbo].[SCHED_RunJob] , MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 20 , EXECUTE AS N'<manager account>'  ), POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING (STATUS = ON)  ON [PRIMARY]` The manager of <manager account> is no longer with the company either. I fully understand that we're running under the risk of accounts being disabled/deleted, however, the Broker is continuing to run. More details in further comments (please let me know if this is not the correct way & what is).

Comment: `CREATE CONTRACT [//ScheduledJobContract] AUTHORIZATION [<manager account>] ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/DialogTimer] SENT BY INITIATOR)` This is the same, no longer with us, manager account as was used to create the queue.

Comment: Is this account a SQL Login? It's possible the account still exists but has no rights any more.

Comment: We do have other tasks that we use in the Broker and they are all running just fine. I've searched through all the various stored procedures that are called by the main procedure (in the part that is failing), and there are no `Execute as` statements

Comment: Yes, it's a SQL login tied to his network login. I agree with you wholeheartedly that the loss of rights on either of the accounts <manager> or <programmer> will cause things to fail. What confuses me is how **some** of this SP is working and other parts failing, and how other SPs are being executed with no issue.

Comment: If it's tied to his network login then it's not a SQL Login, it's a windows domain account. I was asking about that because it's possible the login still works but has no rights. I really can't help without more details about what's working/not working etc.